# Group concat data values by year

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a query that will sum total loss of data by month within a current year.

```
SELECT label, m, coalesce(sum(total_loss), 0) as data
    FROM (
        SELECT label, m
        FROM
        (
            SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) label UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1 
        ) years,

        (
            SELECT 01 m UNION ALL SELECT 02 UNION ALL SELECT 03 UNION ALL SELECT 04
            UNION ALL SELECT 05 UNION ALL SELECT 06 UNION ALL SELECT 07 UNION ALL SELECT 08
            UNION ALL SELECT 09 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
        ) months
    ) ym
    LEFT JOIN incident ON ym.label = YEAR(incident.incident_date) AND ym.m = MONTH(incident.incident_date)
    GROUP BY label, m
```

The data output is

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2017
            [m] => 1
            [data] => 0
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017
        [m] => 2
        [data] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017
        [m] => 3
        [data] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017
        [m] => 4
        [data] => 0
    ) etc..
```

This will output all 12 months, and data does not exist will be 0.

What I'm looking for is some sort of group concat that will output something like this:

```
 {
     data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     label: '2017'},
```

Is it possible to adjust with group concat or write a for each loop to create the data above?

Comment: It would be useful if the json and the array corresponded with each other

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping only by year, and then use `GROUP_CONCAT` on the sums across all months:

```
SELECT
    label,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(SUM(total_loss), 0)) AS data
FROM
(
    SELECT label, m
    FROM
    (
        SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) label UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1 
    ) years,
    (
        SELECT 01 m UNION ALL SELECT 02 UNION ALL SELECT 03 UNION ALL SELECT 04
        UNION ALL SELECT 05 UNION ALL SELECT 06 UNION ALL SELECT 07 UNION ALL SELECT 08
        UNION ALL SELECT 09 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
    ) months
) ym
LEFT JOIN incident
    ON ym.label = YEAR(incident.incident_date) AND
       ym.m = MONTH(incident.incident_date)
GROUP BY label;
```

Comment: Yuk. Well, it's not what I'd do :-(

Comment: @Strawberry I'd love to see your answer then, more than eating strawberry ice cream!

Comment: Your priorities are questionable